# 0 < 2 = ...False?

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-statements, boolean-logic

Python 3.7

Trying to make a number guessing game. Here is my code:

```
#This is the guess the number game!
import random
secretNumber = random.randint(0,20)

print('I am thinking of a secret number between 0 and 20, can you guess what it is in six tries or less?')

for guessTimes in range(1,7):
    try:
        guessNumber = int(input())
        print(type(guessNumber))
        print('Guess Number: ' +str(guessNumber))
    except ValueError:
        guessNumber = None
        print('Secret Number: ' +str(secretNumber))
        print('You have to give me a valid integer for your guess.', end = ' ')
    if guessNumber and guessNumber < secretNumber:
        print('You have guessed a number that is too low...')
    elif guessNumber and guessNumber > secretNumber:
        print('You have guessed a number that is too high...')
    elif guessNumber and guessNumber == secretNumber:
        print('Great job, you guessed the secret number in only ' +str(guessTimes)+ ' tries!')
        print('You should go PRO!')
        break
    if guessTimes > 6:
        print('Sorry, that was six tries and lots of fail, better luck next time!')
    elif guessTimes == 1:
        print('That is ' +str(guessTimes)+ ' failed attempt thus far, you have ' +str(6-guessTimes)+ ' chances remaining. Please try again.')
    elif guessTimes > 1:
        print('That is ' +str(guessTimes)+ ' failed attempts thus far, you have ' +str(6-guessTimes)+ ' chances remaining. Please try again.')
    guessTimes += 1
    continue
```

This all appears to work just fine for all values of guessNumber that are between 1 and 123,412,351. But for some reason, whenever I input 0 as a guessNumber, the code skips the line:

```
if guessNumber and guessNumber < secretNumber:
        print('You have guessed a number that is too low...')
```

I'm sorry this isn't a super-relevant question, but I've been banging my head against this for a while now and can't figure out why that line doesn't evaluate to True when guessNumber == 0.

Comment: Is there any reason for writing you evaluation like :

if guessNumber and guessNumber < secretNumber:

rather writing 

if guessNumber < secretNumber:

Comment: `if guessNumber` will evaluate as False for `guessNumber==0`

Comment: You might want to use a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) for that or look at [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: When the someone inputs a string that can't be converted to int (eg. 'asdfasdf') for their guess and the exception is raised, if I don't set the guessNumber = None, then:

{if guessNumber < secretNumber:}
{NameError: name 'guessNumber' is not defined}

so I'm using

{if guessNumber and guessNumber < secretNumber}

to get a False boolean and skip the clause. Otherwise, if I simply use

{if guessNumber < secretNumber:}
{TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `None` and `0` are "falsy" in Python, so `if guessNumber and guessNumber < secretNumber:` shortcircuits when testing `guessNumber`, since it's `0` and `0` is falsy.

You'll need to narrow your check to only catch `None`, changing tests of the form `if guessNumber and ...:` to `if guessNumber is not None and ...:`.

An alternative solution is to avoid checking the guess entirely when they gave an invalid value. You can do this fairly easily by expanding from `try`/`except` to `try`/`except`/`else`:

```
for guessTimes in range(1,7):
    try:
        guessNumber = int(input())
        print(type(guessNumber))
        print('Guess Number: ' +str(guessNumber))
    except ValueError:
        print('Secret Number: ' +str(secretNumber))
        print('You have to give me a valid integer for your guess.', end = ' ')
    else:
        # Only run when no ValueError occurs
        if guessNumber < secretNumber:
            print('You have guessed a number that is too low...')
        elif guessNumber > secretNumber:
            print('You have guessed a number that is too high...')
        elif guessNumber == secretNumber:
            print('Great job, you guessed the secret number in only ' +str(guessTimes)+ ' tries!')
            print('You should go PRO!')
            break

    if guessTimes == 1:
        print('That is ' +str(guessTimes)+ ' failed attempt thus far, you have ' +str(6-guessTimes)+ ' chances remaining. Please try again.')
    else:
        print('That is ' +str(guessTimes)+ ' failed attempts thus far, you have ' +str(6-guessTimes)+ ' chances remaining. Please try again.')
else:
    # Run when loop exits without break
    print('Sorry, that was six tries and lots of fail, better luck next time!')
```

The advantage here is that you don't bother setting or testing `guessNumber` at all when it's garbage (no using `None` as a flag value or the like), so when it's not garbage, you don't need to check for the flag of `None` at all.

Side-note: In the new code, I removed the `guessTimes += 1` and `continue`, since the `for i in range(1, 7):` already did the increment for you, and a `continue` as the last statement in a loop is nonsensical. I also moved the "too many guesses" output to an `else` on the `for` loop; you'd never have hit that code as written (since the loop ends with `guessTimes` as `6`, `guessTimes > 6` is always false), and it saves checks to just have it happen automatically if the loop ends without a `break`.

Comment: That's elegant. I feel like a caveman stacking rocks next to the Taj Mahal. I will do my best to learn this well and implement these solutions in my future code. Thank you very much, ShadowRanger.

Answer (score 1):

A number if used in conditional statement like `if` is treated as `boolean` (false if 0, true otherwise)

```
if guessNumber and guessNumber < secretNumber:
     print('You have guessed a number that is too low...')
```

There are two conditions here in the if statement and the first one goes false since `guessNumber` for input 0 is false and thus the line gets skipped.

Remove the guessNumber from the condition and you are good

```
if guessNumber < secretNumber:
     print('You have guessed a number that is too low...')
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply with a correct answer, Ubercool. I chose the one from ShadowRanger because it pointed out a variety of flaws in the code that I hadn't even noticed. Upvoted for sure.